# Create virtualenv with a different python version than the system python

Tags: python, virtualenv

My System is:

```
» lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

It has the following system python available:

```
» python --version
Python 2.7.6
» python3 --version
Python 3.4.3

» which python
/usr/bin/python
» which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

I create a virtualenv with python3:

```
» python3 -m venv --without-pip venv3
» source venv3/bin/activate
```

The python version installed is the same as the system python (as expected):

```
» python --version
Python 3.4.3
```

But I would like to have Python 3.5.0 in this virtualenv. Is this possible? Do I need to recompile python? How do I do this *inside* the virtualenv?

Comment: Ah. @snakecharmerb I see. But my push back then would be: why? It's easy and cheap to create a new virtualenv specifying python3.5.0 as the interpreter. If you mess up setting up the venv. Just make a new one.

Comment: @snakecharmerb: not really necessary to keep the old virtualenv, so yes, the linked answer solves my problem. I had to clone and compile python 3.5.1, and use the newly compiled python to create the venv.

Comment: You can use PyCharm